# Coefficient, constant or parameter of Runge-Kutta Method?

Tags: runge-kutta-methods

I confused are $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c_i$ Coefficient, constant or parameter of Runge-Kutta Method? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods
Because there is mention it coefficient, constant and parameter on different site. Thank you!

Comment: What you are discovering is that even when two people use the exact same symbol in the exact same way in the same calculation, they sometimes use different words to describe the symbol. If you look at Kutta's original publication of his method (or at a book that follows his exposition), even the letters used for the symbols are different.

Comment: These numbers are coefficients of expressions in the method, they are constants for the method, they are also parameters defining the method inside a class of similarly structured methods.